# Is it possible to know where the user tapped in a ListView or GridView item in Windows Runtime (Universal) App?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

So I just want to know if I can know whether the user clicked on the left hand side or right hand side of an item in a Clickable ListView or GridView Control in Windows Runtime App. Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Tapped` event which you could try using has a `GetPosition()` method on `TappedRoutedEventArgs` which you could use, which the `ItemClick` event doesn't. You could also try to get the position in the `PointerPressed` event and then use it in `ItemClick` which might work better since `Tapped` might not necessarily work the same way as `ItemClick`.

Really though this just sounds like something that should be avoided as users might not expect a different behavior based on where they click on an item.

Comment: It's actually like they can add a player to either team, so I thought this left/right tap on a single item could work. How would you do it?

Comment: You could do non-clickable items, but in each item include two separate buttons or `RadioButtons` actually.

Comment: +1 - I've missed GetPosition() in Tapped event. @kenshin.thebattosai As i've checked PointerPressed is not fired on every UIElement (for example not on Button) - probably it is handeled before. In this case Tapped event will be better.